# Docker, монтирование папки вне домашней папки пользователя

Tags: docker

Добрый день, мне необходимо подмонтировать к контейнеру к примеру папку c:/projects
команда

```
..... -v //c/projects:/vaw/www .....
```

не срабатывает, 
а команда

```
..... -v //c/Users/User1/projects:/vaw/www .....
```

работает

Дело в ограничении на домашнюю папку, но как ее снать?

Windows 7,
устанавливал через DOCKER TOOLBOX (docker.com/products/docker-toolbox),
не работает = не монтируется диск, 
если попробовать подмонтировать через Kitematic то ругается что диск должен быть доступен для чтения и записи, хотя я на эту папку я выставил полные права для всех.

Comment: что значит не работает? какие ошибки? как установлен докер? какая ОС?

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: Михаил, то и значит, при указании монтируемой папки вне каталога пользователя она не подключается. Докер при этом об ошибке не сообщает.